# .htpasswd pass login from PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have password protected a directory using .htaccess and .htpasswd and all is correctly working.

I have a PHP file that sits outside of the password protected directory, is there a way to pass the login information using this PHP file so that direct access to the folder by URL is not possible but the PHP can access it?

Comment: sure; just include the file by using a full system path to it.

Comment: This “password protection” applies to _HTTP requests_ only, as long as you are operating on the _file system_ with PHP, you don’t need to do anything at all, access is already given.

Comment: As it is written, this question doesn't make sense. *How* do you want PHP to access the protected file? If it's through the file system, it's obviously unrelated and completely irrelevant whether you have htaccess or not, as the previous comments said...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the file to access static content in the folder using php file access without worrying about authentication but if you want to execute a  php file there though a web server (eg: get a cms page using a url) you can use this code to get it using the web url and passing authentication.

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
    )
));
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```